# How does web search work when you provide an exact phrase that has never been indexed?

Tags: search

For instance,

I want to find all documents that contain "green spaghetti and blue meatballs".

If I google search the phrase with quotation marks, google will find all documents that contain that phrase, all the words in that exact order.

Since it is not realistically possible that phrase was indexed, how can google find all the webpages in a fraction of a second?